# matplotlib: limits when using plot and imshow in same axes

Tags: python, plot, scipy, matplotlib

I've been trying to plot an ellipse into an imshow plot. It works, but plotting the ellipse after plotting the image seems to increase xlim and ylim, resulting in a border, which I'd like to get rid of:

[image]

Note that there is NO white border directly after calling imshow only.

My code looks as follows:

```
self.dpi = 100
self.fig = Figure((6.0, 6.0), dpi=self.dpi)
self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
self.canvas.setMinimumSize(800, 400)
self.cax = None
self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
self.axes.imshow(channel1, interpolation="nearest")
self.canvas.draw()
self.axes.plot(dat[0], dat[1], "b-")
```

I've tried setting the limits before and after calling "plot", with no effect

```
# get limits after calling imshow
xlim, ylim = pylab.xlim(), pylab.ylim()
...
# set limits before/after calling plot
self.axes.set_xlim(xlim)
self.axes.set_ylim(ylim)
```

How can I force plot not to increase existing figure limits?

**Solution (thanks to Joe):**

```
#for newer matplotlib versions
self.axes.imshow(channel1, interpolation="nearest")
self.axes.autoscale(False)
self.axes.plot(dat[0], dat[1], "b-")

#for older matplotlib versions (worked for me using 0.99.1.1)
self.axes.imshow(channel1, interpolation="nearest")
self.axes.plot(dat[0], dat[1], "b-", scalex=False, scaley=False)
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What's happening is that the axis is autoscaling to match the extents of each item you plot.  Images are autoscaled much tighter than lines, etc (`imshow` basically calls `ax.axis('image')`).

Getting the axis limits before and setting them after should have worked. (It's cleaner to just do `limits = axes.axis()` before and `axes.axis(limits)` after, though.)

However, if you don't want things to autoscale, it's best to just turn autoscaling off after the initial plot.  Try `axes.autoscale(False)` after plotting the image.

As an example, compare this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)))
ax.plot(range(11))
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

With this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)))
ax.autoscale(False)
ax.plot(range(11))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your detailed explanation! My matplotlib version seems to be too old (matplotlib.__version__ = '0.99.1.1') as it supports neither plt.subplots() nor ax.autoscale, however as you pointed out autoscale=False, I found an [alternative solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386872/make-matplotlib-autoscaling-ignore-some-of-the-plots) that fixes my problem: each time I use plot after initially calling imshow, I use the keyword arguments scalex=False, scaley=False, which does the right thing! Thanks you!