# Plotting point on top of filled contour plot adds lots of blank space

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

I have the following Python code which I am using to plot a filled contour plot:

```
  def plot_polar_contour(values, azimuths, zeniths):
  theta = np.radians(azimuths)
  zeniths = np.array(zeniths)

  values = np.array(values)
  values = values.reshape(len(azimuths), len(zeniths))

  r, theta = np.meshgrid(zeniths, np.radians(azimuths))
  fig, ax = subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
  ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
  ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
  cax = ax.contourf(theta, r, values, 30)
  autumn()
  cb = fig.colorbar(cax)
  cb.set_label("Pixel reflectance")
  show()
```

This gives me a plot like:

[image]

However, when I add the line `ax.plot(0, 30, 'p')` just before `show()` I get the following:

[image]

It seems that just adding that one point (which is well within the original axis range) screws up the axis range on the radius axis.

Is this by design, or is this a bug? What would you suggest doing to fix it? Do I need to manually adjust the axis ranges, or is there a way to stop the extra plot command doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the axis auto-scaling mode isn't explicitly specified, `plot` will use "loose" autoscaling and `contourf` will use "tight" autoscaling.

The same things happens for non-polar axes.  E.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)))
plt.plot([7], [7], 'ro')
plt.show()
```

You have a number of options.

1. Explicitly call `ax.axis('image')` or `ax.axis('tight')` at some point in the code.
2. Pass in `scalex=False` and `scaley=False` as keyword arguments to `plot`.
3. Manually set the axis limits.

The easiest and most readable is to just explicitly call `ax.axis('tight')`, i.m.o.

Comment: Placing `ax.autoscale(False)` after `ax.countourf` but before `ax.plot` is [another option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9120929/190597).

Comment: Thanks. Using `scalex=False` and `scaley=False` solves the problem, but I'd prefer to use `ax.axis('tight')` as it's a bit cleaner, but I can't get that to work. Where should I place the call to `ax.axis('tight')`? I've tried putting it before and after the call to `ax.plot` and before and after the call to `ax.contourf`. Any ideas?

Comment: @unutbu: Thanks, that works fine and is a bit more obvious than some of the other options.

Comment: @robintw - `ax.axis('tight')` will work anywhere in the code with `imshow`, but `contourf` does things a bit differently (I forgot about that...).  `ax.axis('image')` or `ax.axis('tight')` should work fine if you put them after calling `plot`.